# Define a custom distance between classes in Keras

Tags: keras, loss-function

How is it possible to make a classification with custom distance between classes in Keras?

For example, let's say I need to classify between`A1`,`A2`,`B1`,`B2`, but I "prefer" to make a mistake between `A1` and `A2` than between `A1` and`B2`.

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy to implement a custom loss function in Keras, but that may make your model less interpretable, and may make it more difficult to optimize.

You can create a function that takes in the true labels and predicted labels, and returns the loss value and then the function can then be passed to the **compile** method of your Keras model, along with the loss parameter.

Here is an example that you can refer:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def custom_distance(y_true, y_pred):
   # y_true and y_pred are tensors of the same shape
   y_true = tf.argmax(y_true, axis=-1)
   y_pred = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)

   # Calculate the distance between the predicted and true labels
   distance = tf.cast(tf.not_equal(y_true, y_pred), tf.float32)

   # Return a higher distance for mistakes between A1 and B2
   return tf.where(
       tf.logical_and(tf.equal(y_true, 0), tf.equal(y_pred, 2)),
       distance * 2.0,  # Mistake between A1 and B2
       distance         # Other mistakes
   )

# Use the custom distance in your Keras model
model.compile(metrics=[custom_distance])
```